Modify the code in DWL to have a expected result - Mule 4
I try to explain you, I have an Array of Objects:
Input:
[
    { "number": "000001", "price": 14.99, "qty": 18, "line": "3" },
    { "number": "000003", "price": 24.0, "qty": 30, "line": "3" },
    { "number": "000004", "price": 18.0, "qty": 4, "line": "3" }
]

This payload is an example. The array can have more or less "qty" or objects with a similar schema. I am trying to separate the objects dynamically into a new array of objects. The validations are:

I need to append in a new array all the objects that do not pass the sum > 700 (This operation is (price * qty)) and repect more possible the group of SKU.

If we follow the above example:


The first object (000001) will be appended as it is because the sum of (14.99 * 18) = 269.82 does not exceed 700 but if we evaluted the second group of SKU (000003) it's not possible apend the object becuase the sum exceed 720 the limit of 700 and we need to separated but is not possible in this case evaluated the third object and this is possible to apend because not exceed the limit of 700.
[
     { "number": "000001", "price": 14.99, "qty": 18, "line": "3" },
     { "number": "000004", "price": 18.0, "qty": 4, "line": "3" }
]

The next object "000003" has a sum (24 * 30) = 720, this value exceed the limit ob 700 and this case we need to separated the SKU resulting in:
[
    { "number": "000003", "price": 24.0, "qty": 29, "line": "3" }
]

[
    { "number": "000003", "price": 24.0, "qty": 1, "line": "3" }
]

Output:
[
    {
        "object": 1,
        "total": 341.00,
        "items": [
            { "number": "000001", "price": 14.99, "qty": 18, "line": "3" },
            { "number": "000004", "price": 18.0, "qty": 4, "line": "3" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "object": 2,
        "total": 696.00,
        "items": [
            { "number": "000003", "price": 24.0, "qty": 29, "line": "3" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "object": 3,
        "total": 24.00,
        "items": [
            { "number": "000003", "price": 24.0, "qty": 1, "line": "3" }
        ]
    }
]

Summary of the result:

"object" is an iterator or index.
"total" is the sum (price * qty) for all elements in "items".
"items" is the result I explained before.

This is my DWL code, and I don't know how to finish it. I have the idea, but I can't complete it:
%dw 2.0
import update from dw::util::Values
output application/json

fun addToResults(runningResults, currentItem) = do {
    fun updateLastWithItem(runningResults, itemToAdd) = 
        runningResults update (sizeOf(runningResults) - 1) with (
            $ update {
                case .total -> ($ + itemToAdd.qty * itemToAdd.price)
                case .items -> $ << itemToAdd
            }
        )

    var currentItemTotal = currentItem.qty * currentItem.price
    var lastGroupTotal = runningResults[-1].total
    var splittedItem = do {
        var item = currentItem
        var remainingTotal = maxTotal - lastGroupTotal
        var eligibleQty = 
            if(remainingTotal >= maxTotal and item.price > maxTotal) 1
            else min([floor(remainingTotal / item.price), item.qty])
        ---
        {
            eligible: item update "qty" with eligibleQty,
            remaining: item update "qty" with $ - eligibleQty
        }
    }

    ---
    (
        if(splittedItem.eligible.qty > 0) 
            runningResults updateLastWithItem splittedItem.eligible
        else runningResults
    )
    then ((
        if(splittedItem.remaining.qty > 0)
            ($ << defaultGroup) addToResults splittedItem.remaining
        else $
    ))
}

var defaultGroup = {total: 0, items: []}
var maxTotal = 700

---
payload reduce ((item, results = [defaultGroup]) -> 
    results addToResults item
) map {
    object: $$ + 1, 
    ($)
}

This is the result with my code isn't the expected result then I need to apply changes to get the output expected but I dont have idea how, Could you please help me to modify the code if you can have the better idea to have the same logic with new code.
[
  {
    "object": 1,
    "total": 677.82,
    "items": [
      {
        "number": "000001",
        "price": 14.99,
        "qty": 18,
        "line": "3"
      },
      {
        "number": "000003",
        "price": 24,
        "qty": 17,
        "line": "3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "object": 2,
    "total": 384,
    "items": [
      {
        "number": "000003",
        "price": 24,
        "qty": 13,
        "line": "3"
      },
      {
        "number": "000004",
        "price": 18,
        "qty": 4,
        "line": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
]

Thanks a lot.
Sincerely!

Modify the title to indicate what is the issue you are having. This is not a code for free service. Also please don't say DWL, which is a confusing acronym. The tag should be enough.
